# Cant build nginx from source on Redhat

Tags: redhat, gcc

I've done all the installs of dev packages and im trying to build nginx from source.

```
(UAT) root@vstedbm01d# which cc
/bin/cc

(UAT) root@vstedbm01d# which gcc
/bin/gcc
```

When I am in the root of nginx and try to run my configure I get this:

```
(UAT) root@vstedbm01d# /bin/gcc ./configure
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: Which is the output of the command "which ld"? Which RHEL version? Which nginx version are you try to build? Where are downloaded nxing source code?

Comment: @NoNoNo It says no ld in (usr/local etc). Latest nginx and redhat. The sourcecode is in the root folder.

Comment: Start by ensuring that your RHEL subscription is active and installing all available updates.

Answer (score 2):

On a RHEL7 server ld is a file under /bin

```
# which ld
/bin/ld
```

It's provided by binutils package

```
# rpm -qf /bin/ld
binutils-2.27-27.base.el7.x86_64
```

You can verify that your server has:

- binutils installed
- /bin/ld file exists
- PATH environment variable contains /bin

Comment: Hello. I have binutils-2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.1.x86_64 and PATH=$PATH:/bin and I have the /bin/ld file

Comment: Howeever when I do /bin/ld it still says it cant find it

Comment: Can you paste here the output of the command "which ld" and "ls -la /bin/ld" executed with the same user that you use to run the command "./configure"?

Comment: /usr/bin/which: no ld in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin/gcc:/bin/cc:/root/bin:/bin/)

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Feb 15 15:04 /bin/ld -> /etc/alternatives/ld

Comment: Last check: can you verify the output of this commands is similar to mine: # ls -la /etc/alternatives/ld
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15  8 gen 13.27 /etc/alternatives/ld -> /usr/bin/ld.bfd
# ls -la /usr/bin/ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1006232 30 mag  2018 /usr/bin/ld.bfd